# I added APK to AOSP build but it's not visible when I launch the build on Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I had added the apk to an app to my AOSP source code and completed the build successfully. But when I launch the system image on my emulator the app doesn't show up.

I had followed these steps to create the customised build:

1. Created a folder MyApp in the root/packages/apps directory.
2. Added the myApp.apk file to this newly created folder.
3. Created an Android.mk file in this location with the following content:

`LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE = false

LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true

LOCAL_MODULE := MyApp

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS

LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)`

4. Added the name of my folder to PRODUCT_PACKAGES tag in the core.mk file in root/build/target/product.

After these steps I created the build using the commands:
`$ source ./build/envsetup.sh $ lunch sdk_phone_x86 $ make -j32 sdk sdk_repo`

Any fixes for this issue?

Comment: You said "added the name of my folder". In your example here the LOCAL_MODULE and folder name were the same but it's really the LOCAL_MODULE name that matters and annoyingly if use a name in PRODUCT_PACKAGES that doesn't exist the build system silently ignores your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add in   **device/generic/x86/BoardConfig.mk**

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += MyApp
```